# jpa/hibernate drag-n-drop/orm/graphical relations

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, ide

Hey all,
I'm reviewing the IntelliJ ability related to JPA ER Diagrams (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jpa_hibernate.html), and is something I've been looking for a while.

Does anyone know of other tools that have similar abilities, whether as standalone, eclipse plugin, or other alternatives with the intent that the Graphical Tool does bidirectional updates to the persistence.xml/orm.xml?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe have a look at the [JPA Diagram Editor](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/raev/2010/08/18/jpa-diagram-editor-first-milestone-released/) for Eclipse that allows to work on a visual model:

[image]

I don't have any particular experience with it though.